# How to decouple application architecture from React library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're planning to implement our front-end application based on Large-Scale JavaScript Application.

There's a concern in our team to not be coupled to any JavaScript based frameworks like React or Angular.

How could it be designed to be decoupled and independent of React's specific implementation details?

I've already read some articles like ["Patterns For Large-Scale JavaScript Application Architecture"](https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) but still have trouble in implementation.

Comment: Interesting! Independence is almost always a really valuable feature to invest on.

This kind of independence in the field of software development is usually referred to as being 'agnostic'.

Comment: This question is too broad for the site. Please see the [help] pages to see what kinds of questions are a good fit here.